# Transparent line in a line plot?

Tags: sas

Hello intelligent people.

Can anyone tell me how to get a graph/line in a line plot transparent in **SAS EG** or in a **SAS PROC GPLOT procedure**? (2 lines are on top of eachother, so cannot see the underlying line).

Comment: Suggest you add code with sample data and PROC GPLOT, so people can have a starting point to help you.  Usually with a line plot, I wouldn't think overlap would be much of a problem, unless you have really thick lines.  I haven't used GPLOT for a while, but with SGPLOT / GTL there is nice support for transparency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the option `transparency`

```
ods graphics on / width=66%;
data test;
    do x = 1 to 10 by .1;
        up = 11 - x;
        down = 9 - x;
        y = x*x/10;
        output;
    end;

proc sgplot data=test;
    series x=x y=y / lineattrs=(color=orange thickness=3);
    band x=x upper=up lower=down / transparency=.3;
run;
```